# How to store the selected data from a radiobuttonlist which is placed in a repeator in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a survey form wherein I want the responses selected by the survey taker using the radiobuttonlist to be stored in the database. Since I have used a repeator to do this I am unable to get that data

Repeator code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table style="border:1px solid #A55129; background-color:aqua">
                            <tr>
                           <td style="width:200px">
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >

                                        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="Bad"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="Fair"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="Very Good"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="Good"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="Excellent"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

code behind file:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int answer;
    try
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {



                 RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
                answer = Convert.ToInt32((rb.SelectedItem != null) ? rb.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() : "");

              SaveResponse(answer);

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { 
    }
}

private void SaveResponse(int answer)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SurveyUserdataConnectionString2"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string registerquery = "Insert into surveyresponses  (ANSWER) values (@ans)";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(registerquery, conn);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", answer);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: no error as such but it doesn't insert data in the database.its not able to get the data

Comment: This is an old and abandoned question and I think it can be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a **comm.ExecuteQuery()** for the actual insert to happen. That is why you are not seeing the data inserted.

In fact here is a cleaner way of doing the same thing so that all objects are disposed asap.

```
string registerquery = "Insert into surveyresponses  (ANSWER) values (@ans)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SurveyUserdataConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
{
 using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(registerquery, conn))
 {
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", answer);
  comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Is the value 0 or data not inserted? Can you open SQL profiler and see the query being fired.

Comment: the query is executing in sql profiler, but when run through this webpage on button click data is not inserted on button click just the selected data is agn unselected like the page is refreshed.